# ¿Por que no se muestra el valor de los indices del arreglo en las variables indexadas?

Tags: php, mysql

El objetivo de este codigo es realizar una consulta para extraer los valores de las columnas correspondientes y almacenarlos en un arreglo para despues poderlas mostrar en pantalla. Las variables `$prueba1`,`$prueba2`,`$prueba3`,`$prueba4`
estan dentro del codigo HTML anidadas en elementos del tipo `<p>` las cuales sirven para renderizar los valores dentro de las variables pero no estan mostrando nada.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    $varsesion = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    if($varsesion == null || $varsesion = ''){
        echo 'Acceso denegado';
        die();
    }
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','pruebas');
    $consulta = "
        SELECT prueba_uno, prueba_dos, prueba_tres, prueba_cuatro
        FROM usuarios
        WHERE usuario = '".$varsesion."'
    ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    $calificaciones = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

    $prueba1 = $calificaciones[0];
    $prueba2 = $calificaciones[1];
    $prueba3 = $calificaciones[2];
    $prueba4 = $calificaciones[3];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pruebas</h1>
<p><a href="prueba_uno.php">Prueba 1</a></p>
<p><a href="prueba_dos.php">Prueba 2</a></p>
<p><a href="prueba_tres.php">Prueba 3</a></p>
<p><a href="prueba_cuatro.php">Prueba 4</a></p>
<p><a href="cerrar_sesion.php">[x]</a></p>
<p><?php echo $prueba1; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $prueba2; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $prueba3; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $prueba4; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $calificaciones['prueba_uno'] debiera funcionar

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y todavia sigue sin mostrar nada. Me quedo asi:
```<p><?php echo $calificaciones['prueba_uno'] ?></p>``` Y luego me di cuenta de que le hacian falta posiblemente el punto y coma y lo cambie asi:
```<p><?php echo $calificaciones['prueba_uno']; ?></p>```

Comment: Y var_dump($calificaciones)? Enciende el error reporting para descartar un error, por ejemplo por no usar isset en la sesión

Comment: Lo que pasa es que $varsesion no estaba pasando ningun valor, tuve que ponerla en seco asi: ```$_SESSION['usuario']```en la parte del ```WHERE```

Comment: Wait. Estás asignando a var sesión una cadena vacía. Te falta un igual

Comment: Aquí estás asignando un valor vacío a `$varsesion` en la parte del OR (`||`): `if($varsesion == null || $varsesion = ''){` tendrías que ponerlo así: `if($varsesion == null || $varsesion == ''){ //vacio } else { //no vacio }`, podrías hacer una comparación con `empty` también: `if (empty ($varsesion) ) {  //vacío  } else { //tiene datos }`. Evita también el uso de  `die`, hoy día se considera una mala práctica, es preferible que tomes en mano el control de tu código, sin delegar en `die`.

Answer (score 0):

Ese código ejecutado debería mostrarte el mensaje

```
Acceso denegado
```

El código de este bloque siempre se ejecutará, porque la segunda condición no es una comparación (==) sino una asignación (=), que se evalúa a true:

```
if($varsesion == null || $varsesion = ''){
    echo 'Acceso denegado';
    die();
}
```

por eso, al ejecutarse el die() se corta la ejecución del script.

Empieza por sustituir esto:

```
if($varsesion == null || $varsesion = ''){
```

por esto:

```
if($varsesion == null || $varsesion == ''){
```